# How to pass part of an array as function argument in java?

Tags: java, arrays, function, argument-passing

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)       
        printf("%d ",a[i]); 
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    fun(arr+2,3);       
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 3 4 5
The array starting from the 3rd element has been passed here to fun() in C.
How to do the same in JAVA, given that there are no such pointers in JAVA?

In response to one comment below I thought to add the details of what I am actually trying to do as it is too long for the comment section. I need to access only a subsection an array recursively. Actually I am trying to find "median of two sorted arrays by comparing the medians of the two arrays" using the following algo :
1) Calculate the medians m1 and m2 of the input arrays ar1[] 
   and ar2[] respectively.
2) If m1 and m2 both are equal then we are done.
     return m1 (or m2)
3) If m1 is greater than m2, then median is present in one 
   of the below two subarrays.
    a)  From first element of ar1 to m1 (ar1[0...|*n/2*|])
    b)  From m2 to last element of ar2  (ar2[|*n/2*|...n-1])
4) If m2 is greater than m1, then median is present in one
   of the below two subarrays.
   a)  From m1 to last element of ar1  (ar1[|*n/2*|...n-1])
   b)  From first element of ar2 to m2 (ar2[0...|*n/2*|])
5) Repeat the above process until size of both the subarrays 
   becomes 2.
6) If size of the two arrays is 2 then use below formula to get 
  the median.
    Median = (max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1], ar2[1]))/2

Comment: You can't, really.  You could make `fun` take an `offset` argument, though.

Comment: Is your intention to change a subsection of the original array or make a brand new array?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I need to access only a subsection an array recursively. Actually I was trying to find "median of two sorted arrays by comparing the medians of the two arrays" using the following algo :

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Please check the edited question as it is too long to write over here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you **won't modify** the array, you can create a copy of a range using [`Arrays.copyOfRange(int\[\] original, int from, int to)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    fun(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, arr.length), 3);
}

public static void fun(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: which package should be imported for this "Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, arr.length)" function?

Comment: I used " import java.util.*; ", but it's showing "cannot find symbol method copyOfRange(int[],int,int)

Comment: @user3126841 I would recommend you to use an IDE with auto-import. But you can use it by importing `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to pass the start and end indices to the fun method.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    fun(arr, 2, 5);
}

public static void fun(int a[], int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = m; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Response: 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

Because pointer can cause some serious bug or security problems in your program, java does not allow you to manually manipulate pointer as what you can in C. As far as I can think, you have to make a copy of it. You can either use methods from Arrays class provided by java or you can write your own code to do that.